# gulp sass не собирает

Tags: gulp, sass

Почему когда в галпе прогоняю через sass такой код, он выдает ошибку?

> > Проверка содержимого после конката

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Error: ".navbar" failed to @extend "navbar-light".
   The selector "navbar-light" was not found.
   Use "@extend navbar-light !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
    on line 10 of temp/all.scs
```

Вроде потому что не сработали импорты, но почему они не сработали?

> navbar-light это класс из bootstrap/scss/bootstrap

Если удаляю из gulp.src строчку [image: 'app/blocks/**/*.scss'], то импорты проходят и код успешно собирается, но мне нужны файлы стилей из  [image: 'app/blocks/**/*.scss']. Собственно из [image: 'app/blocks/**/*.scss'] подключается класс .navbar

Галп таск выглядит так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понимаю мне надо как-то сделать, чтобы отработали все импорты а потом подключать конкатить блоки из [image: 'app/blocks/**/*.scss'], но это похоже на костыль

Comment: Сделайте все нужные импорты в одном файле (app.scss) и его компилируйте, импорты вставятся в порядке, в котором вы их написали в файле. Если вы пишите `/**/*.scss` он не импортирует файлы, а компилирует каждый файл по отдельности.

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит тк в app/blocks/**/*.scss может быть больше 100 файлов. Не вариант их импортировать в app.scss. Может есть др решение? app.scss для библиотек, личных миксинов, переменных а в blocks/**/*.scss нету импортов только стили для классов

Comment: либо надо как то сделать чтоб в app.scss можно было использовать маску @import blocks/**/*.scss

Comment: насчет "он не импортирует файлы, а компилирует каждый файл по отдельности. " Я ведь использую concat а только потом компелирую